# Use same storecode for different websites

Tags: magento-1, multistore, multidomain, store-code

We have a multistore setup with 3 stores/domains, which should support different languages in the near future and I want to have the locale/language information in store URLs.

**Example:**

- website1.com/en/
- website1.com/fr/
- website2.com/en/
- ...

From the (current) technical background I understand that using same code does not work.

> Store with the same code already exists.

But it is even not allowed to use uppercase codes to work around ...

> The store code may contain only letters (a-z), numbers (0-9) or underscore(_), the first character must be a letter

I could use some "fake" codes, but this is also to limited ...

- website1.com/en/
- website2.com/english/
- website3.com/en_en/

Is there any way to reuse same store? What files have to be adjusted to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed you cannot use the same code for 2 store views.
And I don't recommend removing the restriction since magento counts on the store view code to be unique.

So I don't think there is a way to have the store codes in the url just by enabling them in the backend.
But you can create actual folders named `en`, `fr` and so on and make these folders act as the document root for specific store views.

Here is a detailed explanation on how you can setup multiple websites and store views, each one with its own document root: [Multi-website multi-store set-up](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/79360/146)

Comment: Thanks. I know the subfolders method, but it looks like an ugly workaround. IMHO its truely a missing feature and maybe someone has time to list all the files that have to be adjusted ;)

Comment: please read my answer carefully. Magento expects for the store view code to be unique. It needs to know this in order to know which store view to display. I don't recommend even trying to make it not unique. In my opinion what I propose is not a workaround, it's the safe way to go.

Comment: In my opinion Magento was designed as multistore platform and it should allow such things __w/o__ adding files/folders to root directory. But when you say this is the safe way ... accepted :)

Comment: If it's worth something, I've used it like this on various occasions and it worked properly.

Comment: Yes, it is worth something ;)