# Problem with Multiple Store in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore

I am trying to setup multi store in Magento 1.9.2.3, and here is what I have done so far (in the scenario I am trying to create another store for France and call it "FR"):

1) Creating a new root Catalog,

2) Creating a new `Website/Store/StoreView` in System >> Manage Stores

3) Creating a new directory called "fr" in magento root folder and I have copied "Index.php" and ".htaccess" file from magento root to "fr" folder.

4) I have edited the "index.php" file inside "fr" folder from

```
$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/Mage.php';
```

TO

```
$mageFilename = '../app/Mage.php';
```

5) and I have added below code into the ".htaccess" of "fr" folder:

```
SetEnvIf Host .*base.* MAGE_RUN_CODE="base";

SetEnvIf Host .*magento_site_2.* MAGE_RUN_TYPE="fr";
```

I have also set the "Auto-redirect to Base URL" to **disabled** in the admin panel, and set the "secure" and "Not-secure" base url for "fr" store accordingly.

**The Problem** is, when I try to access the new store by going to `www.example.com/fr/`, I can see the **exact** same website with all the products and categories that are available in `www.example.com`. It does not feel like a new empty store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Marius](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/146/marius) has explained this scenario **perfectly** here: [Multi-website multi-store set-up](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/79358/multi-website-multi-store-set-up/79360#79360)

---

*Just ensure that you have assigned your root (catalog) category correct in website configuration.*

Comment: Problem solved by following the link you shared. I was missing some code replacement in the new "index.php" file. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can run multistore from same directory (for default website) without having to create a separate sub directory. So rest of the process is same but doesn't involve creating subdirectory for store "fr". Just go to System->Configuration->Web (from left menu) Url Option and select **Yes** under **Add Shop Code to URLs**
Assuming your shop code is fr, you can now access your store via `www.example.com/fr/`

You don't need to add any code to htaccess file for this to work.

Comment: How about if I want to create a new website in Magento (not just store,  and store view). Can I still ignore the part where I create the "fr" folder in the root folder of magento  manually?

Comment: Yes, you can create a new website and assign it a new store view. Rest of the process stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

You also set the store base url for each store view.

Go to `system->configuration->web`. Select the fr store view from the top left selector and under the `Unsecure url` fill in this for the base url `http://www.example.com/fr`/.

Do the same for the Secure urls if you have them enabled (and use https).

Comment: Please check and let me know it is work

Answer (score 0):

You just have to create your store and store view by setting "**fr**" in "`code field`", the root category of this store that you have created before etc... then the products of this root category will be visible just in this store.

Yo can access directly to your store via **Url** like this: `http://www.domaine.com?___store=fr` without enabling "`Add Shop Code to URLs`" field and creating a new root folder.