# Magento2 multiwebsite multistore sharing storeview code

Tags: magento2.4, multistore, multi-website, store-code

We have a Magento 2.4 project with multiple websites with multiple stores & we need to **share** some "**store codes**" in url terms for store views. All store views should load under same domain

Document root of this project is pointing to **magento/pub** folder, as recommended

URL structure should be a bit different than usual

I'll try to explain using some concrete url strings, so answers can use them, for clarity

```
Website1 (es)
------------- Store1 -------- Storeview (es_hair)
              Store2 -------- Storeview (es_pets)
Website2 (fr)
------------- Store1 -------- Storeview (fr_hair)
              Store2 -------- Storeview (fr_pets)
```

They should run under this urls

```
www.domain.com/es/hair/ 
www.domain.com/es/pets/
www.domain.com/fr/hair/
www.domain.com/fr/pets/
```

How can we achieve this?

Using nginx configuration would NOT be the desired way. We'd like to follow some approach like [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/79358/multi-website-multi-store-set-up/79360#79360) using folders but we've tried with no success, so I open this question to try understanding this better. Please use the provided concrete urls in your answers so we can try. Apart from the filesystem changes I need to know too the required configuration changes in admin

**UPDATE**

We have this *working* but still some doubts. What we've done:

We have created this folders at **magento/pub** folder

```
/es/hair
/es/pets
/fr/hair
/fr/pets
```

In this folders we have copied both **.htaccess** & **index.php** files from **magento/pub** folder

**.htaccess** file has the same code (first doubt: something to do with `RewriteBase` here?)

In **index.php** file we have changed the path to **bootstrap.php** & we have added this parameters, so we force Magento to load a concrete storeview

```
$params = $_SERVER;
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] <- code of the storeview here
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'store';
```

We have added 2 symlinks **media** & **static** to **magento/pub/media** & **magento/pub/static** folders

With this the website and all store views seem to be loading fine by setting global parameter "use store code in urls" : "no" & setting `base_url` to [www.domain.com/es/hair/](http://www.domain.com/es/hair/) and so on for every storeview

Another doubt, which files should we add in first level folders (/es, /fr)? I understand we'd need some **.htaccess** file there

And the last & big doubt: would this be enough? or are we missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Multi-Store Setup (Apache)**

> **Create a virtual host for your main example.com**

```
sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/{virtualname}com.conf
```

> **Here {virtualname} is the file name you can add any name as you need. Our hostname is an example then we used that name.**

```
sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/examplecom.conf
```

> **After creating please open that file. And add below code content(must be open with root user):**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example/pub

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/html/example/pub>
          Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
          AllowOverride All
          Order allow,deny
          allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

> **Now we are enabling this site file using the below command:**

```
sudo a2ensite examplecom.conf
```

> **Add your new hostname into the system hosts file using the below command:**

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

> **After opening the file please add this:**

```
127.0.0.1 example.com
127.0.0.1 www.example.com
```

> **When you enable any site file or add a new host then you must restart the service using the below command:**

```
sudo systemctl reload apache2

Ubuntu: service apache2 restart

CentOS: service httpd restart
```

**After the above process http://example.com/ URL is working. Now we set up a multi-store URL. as per your requirement multi-store folders are created into /var/www/html/example/pub directory. Here we are creating two folders wholesale and retail.**

```
cd /var/www/html/example/pub

mkdir wholesale

mkdir retail
```

**After making the directory, we need to copy the index.php and .htaccess file from /var/www/html/example/pub directory and place it into your newly created folders (wholesale and retail).**

**index.php**

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

try {
    require __DIR__ . '/../../app/bootstrap.php';
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo <<<HTML
<div style="font:12px/1.35em arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">
    <div style="margin:0 0 25px 0; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">
        <h3 style="margin:0;font-size:1.7em;font-weight:normal;text-transform:none;text-align:left;color:#2f2f2f;">
        Autoload error</h3>
    </div>
    <p>{$e->getMessage()}</p>
</div>
HTML;
    exit(1);
}

$params = $_SERVER;
$params[Bootstrap::INIT_PARAM_FILESYSTEM_DIR_PATHS] = array_replace_recursive(
    $params[Bootstrap::INIT_PARAM_FILESYSTEM_DIR_PATHS] ?? [],
    [
        DirectoryList::PUB => [DirectoryList::URL_PATH => ''],
        DirectoryList::MEDIA => [DirectoryList::URL_PATH => 'media'],
        DirectoryList::STATIC_VIEW => [DirectoryList::URL_PATH => 'static'],
        DirectoryList::UPLOAD => [DirectoryList::URL_PATH => 'media/upload'],
    ]
);
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication(\Magento\Framework\App\Http::class);
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

> **Do not copy the root .htaccess file. Copy pub directory .htaccess file. And add the below line:**

```
# SET MULTI-STORE CODE NAME

SetEnvIf Host .*example.* MAGE_RUN_CODE=YourWebsiteCode
SetEnvIf Host .*example.* MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
```

[image]

**Get your website code. Go Stores -> Configuration -> Settings -> All Stores**

**Now you must restart the service using the below command:**

```
sudo systemctl reload apache2

Ubuntu: service apache2 restart

CentOS: service httpd restart
```

***Note: You must be added the URL in your Magento core_config_data table.***

```
http://example.com/
http://example.com/wholesale/
http://example.com/retail/
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will accept this. But, can you read the update I added & answer the concrete doubts?

Comment: Yes, that's enough. And I posted above which files should be placed, and on which path.

Answer (score -1):

IMO it's ugly but you can add directory in pub directory like:

pub/store_code/index.php

Duplicate the main index.php in all new directories and add that:

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

try {
    require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo <<<HTML
<div style="font:12px/1.35em arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">
    <div style="margin:0 0 25px 0; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">
        <h3 style="margin:0;font-size:1.7em;font-weight:normal;text-transform:none;text-align:left;color:#2f2f2f;">
        Autoload error</h3>
    </div>
    <p>{$e->getMessage()}</p>
</div>
HTML;
    exit(1);
}

$params = $_SERVER;
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'store';
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = 'your_store_ce';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication(\Magento\Framework\App\Http::class);
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

Comment: Sorry, but that's practically the same I posted in the UPDATE part. By the way, you don't answer the doubts I ask in the question